# Why Platform as a service?

Tags: saas, force.com, paas

I am currently in the early stages of my project which is an ERP application that I plan to sell to enterprise clients. I heard about the Force.com platform but I'm confused on what benefits will I gain if I use it and not develop my own. Can you please explain why should I use Force.com or any PaaS?

Regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disadvantages of the Force.com platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664503/disadvantages-of-the-force-com-platform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has a simple answer. Building and operating such a platform is not an easy and trivial task in both business and technical perspective.

Of course, you may choose to develop your own platform but i think it would take a long time with much more money and efforts. I know it because I have been working for a company which is developing such a platform ( [Viravis](http://www.viravis.com) ).

Comment: Thanks @orka, but i'm still concerned about having this dependency on the PaaS. What if the service goes down, so does my business right?

Comment: Yes, you are right @drikoda but I think that there will be always an option (data exporting, going the way of open source, free on-premise installation, giving source code etc) for service down which is provided by the provider to  allow you to continue your business without any problem.