# Disadvantages of Salesforce CRM

Tags: salesforce, crm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disadvantages of the Force.com platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664503/disadvantages-of-the-force-com-platform)

What are the disadvantages of Salesforce CRM compared to other CRM systems available in the market? In terms of ease of use, cost, integration with other systems etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664503/disadvantages-of-the-force-com-platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce.com Key disadvantages include:

- Overly simple user interface that is quickly outgrown by experienced
  users.
- Lots of screen refreshes and scrolling up and down; the transition between multiple screens to process transactions can deliver a tedious experience.
- Marketing management functionality is extremely limited. SFDC points to partner applications for this purpose. This involves additional costs and vendor management.
- Customization toolkits can be cumbersome to use, even to many seasoned administrators.
- Dashboards may not reflect the application security for specific users
  without significant administration effort.
- No Service Level Agreement provided in standard contract.
- Data center reliability has been questioned and several major interruptions in service have been widely publicized.

Compared to Microsoft Dynamics it is

- More expensive
- Not as highly configurable
- Only available in SaaS deployment