# Upload a java/php/python.. application on Force.com

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I am doing a survey about cloud paltforms and I have the following the question:

Is it possible to upload a Java/PHP/Python/etc application on Force.com just like you can do with Google App Engine, Heroku, Openshift, etc.?

I looked at the Salesforce website but I couldnt reach a certain conclusion. If I understood correctly, you can upload the code on Heroku and then integrate the application with features of Force.com or something like that.

Could someone shed some light here? Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force.com has his own language to run custom **code on server**. This language is called **APEX**.

> Apex is a strongly-typed, object-oriented programming language that
>   lets you centralize and execute flow and transaction control
>   statements on the Force.com platform in conjunction with application
>   calls to Force.com ​APIs. Using syntax that looks like Java and acts
>   like database stored procedures, Apex lets you add powerful custom
>   business logic to most system events, including button clicks, related
>   record updates, and Visualforce pages. Web service requests and
>   database triggers on objects can also initiate the execution of Apex
>   code.

More info in [the official apex doc](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex)

But you **can't upload** to salesforce servers any kind of standard code like php/python. If you need to develop your own app using php/python/java + salesforce-api's you will have to upload/run this code on your own server.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku and [database.com](http://database.com) are closer to what you're after. Heroku will let you upload you Python/Java etc. app and then you can easily connect it to Salesforce-style database.

By "style" I mean one in which you can still use this Apex language in triggers for example or expose pieces of Apex to be called via webservices. Such webservices could be used like "stored procedures" in classic solutions - if you'd want to keep part of the logic on the Force.com side rather than in your app.

Martin's answer is very good. If it's not immediately obvious - there's a "vendor lock-in". You can't run this Apex code anywhere else, only on SF server. There's no open source equivalent like LAMP stack for PHP, Tomcat for Java etc.

I think it will make sense for you to read these 2 questions from "related" sidebar: [Disadvantages of the Force.com platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664503/disadvantages-of-the-force-com-platform) and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363333/anyone-moved-off-force-com. They're a bit negative but for your pros/cons type of comparison should give you some highlights.